# How to register custom FileSystemBinaryLargeObject

Tags: codefluent

How to configure codefluent runtime in odrder to plug in a custom class which inherits from FileSystemBinaryLargeObject ?

In our use case we have an entity with more than 100k files. I need to figure out how to chunk them in subdirectories..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all entities:

```
<configuration>
 <configSections>
   <section name="MyDefaultNamespace" type="CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentConfigurationSectionHandler, CodeFluent.Runtime" />
 </configSections>
 <MyDefaultNamespace ... other attributes ...
  binaryServicesTypeName="CustomBinaryServices, Assembly"
  binaryServicesEntityConfigurationTypeName="CustomBinaryServicesConfiguration, Assembly"
  />
</configuration>
```

For a specific entity:

```
<configuration>
 <configSections>
   <section name="MyDefaultNamespace" type="CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentConfigurationSectionHandler, CodeFluent.Runtime" />
 </configSections>
 <MyDefaultNamespace ... other attributes ... >
   <binaryServices entityFullTypeName="MyDefaultNamespace.MyNamespace.MyEntity"
     binaryServicesTypeName="CustomBinaryServices, Assembly" 
     binaryServicesEntityConfigurationTypeName="CustomBinaryServicesConfiguration, Assembly"/>
 </MyDefaultNamespace>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you propose doesn't work. I've tested it to see my custom blob class is not getting instantiated.

According to the code below @binaryServicesTypeName attribute accepts only 4 predefined string values
: azure, azure2, filesystem, skydrive.

Otherwise the default "SqlServerBinaryLargeObject" blob object is set.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the type name of the class deriving from the BinaryLargeObject class.
///             Based on the 'typeName' Xml attributes from the configuration file.
///             The default is SqlServerBinaryLargeObject.
/// 
/// </summary>
/// 
/// <value>
/// The configured type name.
/// </value>
public virtual string TypeName
{
  get
  {
    if (this._typeName == null)
    {
      string defaultValue = (string) null;
      if (this._configuration.PersistenceHook != null)
        defaultValue = this._configuration.PersistenceHook.BinaryLargeObjectTypeName;
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultValue))
        defaultValue = typeof (SqlServerBinaryLargeObject).AssemblyQualifiedName;
      this._typeName = XmlUtilities.GetAttribute((XmlNode) this.Element, "binaryServicesTypeName", defaultValue);
      if (this._typeName == null)
        this._typeName = XmlUtilities.GetAttribute((XmlNode) this.Element, "typeName", defaultValue);
      if (this._typeName != null && string.Compare(this._typeName, "azure", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        this._typeName = "CodeFluent.Runtime.Azure.AzureBinaryLargeObject, CodeFluent.Runtime.Azure";
      if (this._typeName != null && string.Compare(this._typeName, "azure2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        this._typeName = "CodeFluent.Runtime.Azure.AzureBinaryLargeObject, CodeFluent.Runtime.Azure2";
      if (this._typeName != null && string.Compare(this._typeName, "filesystem", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        this._typeName = typeof (FileSystemBinaryLargeObject).AssemblyQualifiedName;
      if (this._typeName != null && string.Compare(this._typeName, "skydrive", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        this._typeName = typeof (SkyDriveBinaryLargeObject).AssemblyQualifiedName;
    }
    return this._typeName;
  }
  set
  {
    this._typeName = value;
  }
}
```

other ideas ?

PS: here is app.config demo file using generated schema for codefluent runtime

[app.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SibE8.png)